# Python: how to generate a scale-free network with pre-defined node positions?

Tags: python, dictionary, grid, networkx

I want to generate a scale-free network following the *Barabasi-Albert* algorithm involving *growth* and *preferential attachment*.

I use the following script to create the network:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n=100 #Number of nodes
m=4 #Number of initial links
seed=100
G=nx.barabasi_albert_graph(n, m, seed)
nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

This produces the following output:
[image]

**I am not happy with how the nodes are positioned.** I want them to be positioned according to a pre-defined scheme which resembles a regular grid, while still maintaining the scale-free features:

[image]

I can create a dictionary of positions which reflects my grid:

```
pos = dict( (n, n) for n in G.nodes() )
labels = dict( ((i, j), i + (n-1-j) * n ) for i, j in G.nodes() )
inds=labels.keys()
vals=labels.values()
inds.sort()
vals.sort()
pos2=dict(zip(vals,inds))
```

**My question:** how can I modify the script to obtain a Barabasi-Albert graph with the node positions specified in `pos2`, which is to say according to my grid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 100  # Number of nodes
m = 4  # Number of initial links
seed = 100
G = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(n, m, seed)

ncols = 10
pos = {i : (i % ncols, (n-i-1) // ncols) for i in G.nodes()}
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True)    
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Transposing the modules and integer division operators transposes the rows and columns:

```
pos = {i : (i // ncols, (n-i-1) % ncols) for i in G.nodes()}
```

yields

[image]

---

Changing the y-value from `(n-i-1) % ncols` to `ncols - (n-i-1) % ncols` flips the image about a horizonal axis:

```
pos = {i : (i // ncols, ncols - (n-i-1) % ncols) for i in G.nodes()}
```

Comment: Lovely layout - add more noes and see why a directed graph starts becoming a necessity, not a luxury.

Comment: How to change node positions so that the first row becomes the first column? e.g., having the nodes labelled row-wise instead of column-wise.

Comment: @CF84: Transpose the `%` and `//` operators. I've added code above to show what I mean.

Comment: Sorry for asking again, but it is complicated for me, as it is not entirely clear which is the iterator for the row and which one is for the column. What if I would like nodes 9, 19, 29, ..., 99 to be shown on the upper row rather than on the lower one? This means reflecting node positions with respect to an horizontal line crossing the network right in between the row starting with node 4 and that starting with node 5. Thanks.

Comment: If you are plotting points `(x, y)` where y goes from `0` to `N`. Then to flip the plot horizontally so the point with `y-value` `0` now at `N` and the point with `y-value` `N` now at `0`, you would plot `(x, N-y)`. Similarly, if you change `(n-i-1) % ncols` to `ncols - (n-i-1) % ncols`, the image will be flipped about a horizontal axis.

Answer (score 1):

How many nodes are you planning on placing on the Graph ?
Once you start getting more than 100 - unless you have an amazing amount of visual real-estate it often becomes totally pointless adding any more nodes.

I have used several tools in the past - and never found one to be the overall best

```
* pygraph
* A Microsoft Graphing engine
* GraphDb - lots of query node power there
* IBM Products - for spacial visualisation
```

Most graphing packages leave the node placement up to the package - I have not used (nor do I want to use one) which makes this a task of the Data Scientist/Software Engineer

Interested to see how you get on however...

Comment: I plan to add 20000 nodes, but visualization is not a problem I am concerned with. So you suggest moving away from `networkx`?

Comment: 20k Nodes !!! Err I started off the other day with 80K.... filtered and threw that on a visual graph with 800 key pairs.... it was literally a BLACK HORRIBLE MESS !!!  When I then applied some filtering to the 800 key pairs (and reduced to around 250 items) then you could discern some information regarding the network chart. If you are not concerned about visualisation then why worry where the nodes are being place on the graph ?

Comment: Because this script is paired with another script in which computations are carried out, and they are based on the node positions.

Comment: Ok - that makes total sense. So (assuming I have understood this) - you populate your Barabási–Albert  model - and the most popular-nodes generally will get more links (Ok).... as long as you can query the graph to find out the node's edges I would not worry about the placement (unless the node has a GEO relationship). Your Python code to place the nodes looks ok... It is getting the network to auto balance and re-order itself at 20K nodes will be VERY CPU intensive. I forgot also to mention graphX - well worth a look also - Apache, Spark, bigdata etc

Comment: The nodes have GEO relationships. But what if I generate one single scale-free network and write to a csv file its `G.edges()`? It is this object which possesses the power law features typical of this network. I could then add 20000 nodes based on my positions and later add the edges with `G.add_edge()` from the csv file. Could it be a sensible workaround?